# Output XML data to CSV text file using C# XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, csv

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and working with a Visual C# / XAML WPF project.

What I have is an .xml document that contains values I would like to read, manipulate, and output the results to a comma delimited .csv file with specific headers. I believe I have already got most of the code correct, but there seems to be an issue with the levels of nested elements. This code successfully creates a .csv, but it is always just blank.

I've already experimented with the .Descendants() and .Elements() part of the code, but cannot get anything to be written to the file. I think I can achieve my goal by using the XDocument class and wish to not use any other resources if possible.

Any help is appreciated! This is my first time posting here so if any additional information is needed, I will be glad to add more.

C# Code:

```
private void testMethod()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string delimiter = ",";

        XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Paulie\Desktop\Flight1.xml")
                   .Descendants("trk")
                   .Elements()
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(element => sb.Append(
            element.Attribute("lon").Value + delimiter +
            element.Attribute("lat").Value + delimiter +
            element.Element("ele").Value + delimiter +
            element.Element("time").Value + delimiter +
            element.Element("course").Value + delimiter +
            element.Element("pitch").Value + delimiter +
            element.Element("roll").Value +
            "\r\r"));

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Paulie\Desktop\Flight1.csv");
        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        sw.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

XML Source Sample (The unfriendly version, exactly as it is written in the XML text):

```
<gpx creator="Mission Planner 1.3.29 build 1.1.5646.37690" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"><trk><trkseg><trkpt lat="30.3020034" lon="-96.4781874"><ele>89.96</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:16-05:00</time><course>56.32</course><roll>-3.11</roll><pitch>-5.99</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020015" lon="-96.4781862"><ele>89.45</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:19-05:00</time><course>56.3</course><roll>-3.06</roll><pitch>-6.06</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020013" lon="-96.4781861"><ele>89.42</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:19-05:00</time><course>56.3</course><roll>-3.06</roll><pitch>-6.11</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020012" lon="-96.478186"><ele>89.38</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:19-05:00</time><course>56.29</course><roll>-3.05</roll><pitch>-6.14</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.302001" lon="-96.4781859"><ele>89.35</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00</time><course>56.29</course><roll>-3.06</roll><pitch>-6.13</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020009" lon="-96.4781858"><ele>89.32</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00</time><course>56.28</course><roll>-3.07</roll><pitch>-6.17</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020007" lon="-96.4781856"><ele>89.29</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00</time><course>56.27</course><roll>-3.08</roll><pitch>-6.17</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020005" lon="-96.4781855"><ele>89.25</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00</time><course>56.26</course><roll>-3.1</roll><pitch>-6.2</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020004" lon="-96.4781854"><ele>89.22</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00</time><course>56.26</course><roll>-3.1</roll><pitch>-6.21</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020003" lon="-96.4781853"><ele>89.2</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:21-05:00</time><course>56.25</course><roll>-3.1</roll><pitch>-6.24</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3020002" lon="-96.4781852"><ele>89.17</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:21-05:00</time><course>56.24</course><roll>-3.12</roll><pitch>-6.26</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.302" lon="-96.4781851"><ele>89.16</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:21-05:00</time><course>56.23</course><roll>-3.12</roll><pitch>-6.29</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3019999" lon="-96.478185"><ele>89.13</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:21-05:00</time><course>56.23</course><roll>-3.12</roll><pitch>-6.32</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3019998" lon="-96.4781848"><ele>89.09</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:22-05:00</time><course>56.2</course><roll>-3.09</roll><pitch>-6.36</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3019997" lon="-96.4781847"><ele>89.08</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:22-05:00</time><course>56.2</course><roll>-3.09</roll><pitch>-6.38</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3019996" lon="-96.4781846"><ele>89.06</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:22-05:00</time><course>56.21</course><roll>-3.1</roll><pitch>-6.28</pitch><mode /></trkpt><trkpt lat="30.3019995" lon="-96.4781845"><ele>89.04</ele><time>2016-08-30T08:46:22-05:00</time><course>56.2</course><roll>-3.1</roll><pitch>-6.22</pitch><mode /></trkpt></trkseg></trk></gpx>
```

Expected Output Sample:

```
TimeStamp,SensorLatitude,SensorLongitude,SensorAltitude,PlatformHeading,PlatformPitch,PlatformRoll
1472525176000000,30.3020034,-96.4781874,89.96,56.32,-5.99,-3.11
1472525179000000,30.3020015,-96.4781862,89.45,56.3,-6.06,-3.06
1472525179000000,30.3020013,-96.4781861,89.42,56.3,-6.11,-3.06
1472525179000000,30.3020012,-96.478186,89.38,56.29,-6.14,-3.05
1472525180000000,30.302001,-96.4781859,89.35,56.29,-6.13,-3.06
1472525180000000,30.3020009,-96.4781858,89.32,56.28,-6.17,-3.07
```

(Note that the TimeStamp column contains integer values instead of a date-time format. This is the one field that I need to change using another function that converts a date-time format to a Posix/Unix time signature)

Comment: It would be great to also see an example of the output format you expect the csv to be in.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added a small sample of the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Elements()` gets all child elements. When you do this:

```
.Descendants("trk").Elements()
```

You are selecting all the `trkseg` elements (the child elements of `trk` elements). Your data is inside of the `trkpt` elements, so you probably want something like this:

```
XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Paulie\Desktop\Flight1.xml")
    .Descendants("trkpt")
    .ForEach(...);
```

Additionally, because your XML is in a namespace, you will need to specify that when looking for nodes:

```
.Descendants("{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}trkpt")
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps to clarify what parameter I should pass to .Descendants(). Unfortunately, setting it to "trkpt" still creates a blank file. Maybe I should separate some of the code out instead of trying to bundle the whole function into one line.

Comment: I don't know what `ForEach` is from but I'm guessing it is returning a cold `IEnumerable`, so your code there isn't actually getting executed.

Comment: Also, your XML is using namespaces, which explains why nothing would be found via XLinq. Updated answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know. I wish I had more experience with this stuff, as I'm finding that it's quite difficult to make it work >_<

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
string[] valuesToPrint = { "lon", "lat", "ele", "time", "course", "pitch", "roll" };
XNamespace ns = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1";
File.WriteAllLines("Flight1.csv",
    new[] { string.Join(",", valuesToPrint) }
    .Concat(XDocument.Load("Flight1.xml")
    .Descendants(ns + "trkpt")
    .Select(e =>
    {
        return string.Join(",", e.Attributes()
            .Where(a => valuesToPrint.Contains(a.Name.LocalName))
            .Select(a => a.Value)
            .Concat(e.Elements()
                .Where(c => valuesToPrint.Contains(c.Name.LocalName))
                .Select(c => c.Value)).ToArray());
    })));
```

Output using your test XML:

```
lon,lat,ele,time,course,pitch,roll
-96.4781874,30.3020034,89.96,2016-08-30T08:46:16-05:00,56.32,-3.11,-5.99
-96.4781862,30.3020015,89.45,2016-08-30T08:46:19-05:00,56.3,-3.06,-6.06
-96.478186,30.3020012,89.38,2016-08-30T08:46:19-05:00,56.29,-3.05,-6.14
-96.4781859,30.302001,89.35,2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00,56.29,-3.06,-6.13
-96.4781858,30.3020009,89.32,2016-08-30T08:46:20-05:00,56.28,-3.07,-6.17
```

As I'm not sure of the exact format you want your output to be, this may be a little off the mark!

This breaks down as follows:

- Write every line in the following collection to the file "Flight1.csv"
- The first element in the collection is the header names joined by a comma
- All subsequent elements correspond to every trkpt entry in the XML
- For every trkp entry, select the values for all attributes and child elements whose name is contained in `valuesToPrint` and join those values by a comma.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much! I am getting the header row in the CSV file this time, but for some reason none of the fields are being written. I will keep tweaking it.

Comment: I'm guessing that the actual source XML (the one I updated in the original post) is actually slightly different than the one your function uses. Maybe this is why I am not getting anything else to write to the file. Do you have a suggestion as to how my original method might be adjusted to work?

Comment: So far, this is the only method that I can get to produce any sort of output to write to the .CSV file. Would it make sense that I have to specify the namespace somehow to get the actual data to be written to the file as well?

Comment: Ah, sorry - you are correct, in my simplified version I removed the namespace. I have updated my example with how you can do this and it appears to work with the new XML you posted.

Answer (score 0):

After working with the original XML source for a while, I realized that there was a bunch of extra data at the beginning and end of the file that was totally unnecessary and did nothing more than cause issues with my program.

What I ended up doing is chopping off the beginning and end parts of the XML code (using  and  as start and end indexes) so that I could easily use my original method of transforming the XML structure into a CSV structure.

All is working now! Thanks to everyone who spent time assisting me.